# Does ZFC allow for the existence of any paradoxical sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

ZFC doesn't allow for classes like the Russell Set (aptly named as a set I suppose...) to be sets, but my question is the following:

In general, if X is a set in the ZFC universe, then for some sentence, A(X), can it be the case that A(X) iff not A(X)?

Comment: Obviously, nobody has ever found such example, as otherwise ZFC would not be so widely used and accepted. But we cannot be sure, however.

Comment: Right - it seems like the core advantage of an axiomatic set theory is just to make it explicitly clear what the universe of sets is, but it says nothing about the possible existence of a set within that universe that might give rise to a contradiction. We just want to have a rigorous way of ruling out the things we know we do not want to admit as sets.

Comment: "...to make it explicitly clear what the universte of sets is" Be careful, this is another slippery slope. First, there may be many *models* which may be quite strange. Secondly, the existence of many "sets" described by their properties is known to be undecidable (independent from axioms) in ZFC. But in general yes, it is a formal attempt to make things rigorous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to make a few points about this question.

As aptly pointed in Hanul's answer, there is no consistent theory which proves any contradictory sentence, and in particular, any sentence of the form $\phi \iff \neg \phi$. Furthermore, every inconsistent theory proves all contradictions, since inconsistent theories prove every sentence.

But, what does it mean that a theory proves a sentence?

The answer has to be seen from a formalist's perspective. The exact definition is that it can be deduced from the theory axioms, where a deduction is a chain of what is widely agreed as sound steps of deduction, such as *modus ponens*, etc.

We hope that it is indeed the case that $ZFC$ does not prove any contradiction, but even in the optimistic case where we $ZFC$ is consistent, we have no way of proving so **from the axioms of $ZFC$ itself**, due to Gödel's second incompleteness theorem, concrete form.

Now, we can make a new theory which includes as an axiom the consistence of $ZFC$ plus the normal axioms of $ZFC$, and so its consistency would be vacuously proven. But such a proof would be meaningless, since inconsistent theories prove everything, even false statements. And even we could do the same including the inconsistency of $ZFC$ as an axiom, and we would have no clue as to whether the resulting theory would be inconsistent or not (thought it would be $\omega$-inconsistent for sure).

We could however find an inconsistency in the same way Russell annihilated the original Set Theory of Frege: By Way of Contradiction.

Those problems are not exclusive of $ZFC$,by the way. Every theory complex enough to talk about Peano Arithmetic will fall prey to the same problems. So the best we can do for now is hope that the theory does not blow up in our face and someone finds a contradiction.

Comment: As a philosophical question, why not just naively define sets, and adopt the convention that if a paradoxical set appears within a mathematical proof, it invalidates the proof? Is a paradox free theory of sets necessary for doing mathematics?

Comment: @Searching_for_a_foundation There are some interesting things to be said about that. Consider the following question: What would happen if we found a contradiction in PA? Certainly the universe would not collapse into nothingness (citation needed), and the mathematical equations describing physics would work just as fine. The most promising way out of trouble in this scenario is to develop a formal framework to reason about 'logical counterfactuals'; that is, inferences which work even in the presence of contradictions (kind of what you propose in your comment).

Comment: (continuation) Some paraconsistent systems of logic try to circumvent this problem by eliminating some of the deduction steps we now consider sound, but the truth is that we are still very confused about logical counterfactuals, and is so an open problem. The problem it is interesting in its own right, as it has applications in game theory: after all, it seems very natural that to reach the optimal solution you may want to ponder about what would happen if you take such and such action, but in the end you only take one action, rendering the other logically inconsistent with the scenario.

Comment: Overall, I think we just need some rigorous way to create proofs. A formal framework in this case would just be some agreed-upon rules of inference, which can applied to whatever definitions and hypotheses we choose to use.

Answer (score 0):

$A(x)$ can not be equivalent to $\lnot A(x)$; its proof even not requires ZFC. That is because we can prove $\phi$ is not equivalent to $\lnot\phi$ from axioms of (first-order) logic. 
Moreover, if our theory is consistent then there is no way to find "paradoxical" sets. The bad news is that we do not know whether ZFC is consistent or not.